# Running SDL library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, sdl-2, qmake

so ive been trying to run this monopoly code using Qt creator IDE. I also have used SDL to try and render the project. It keeps giving me that it cannot find -ISDL, although in my .pro file i included the appropriate paths

```
LIBS += -L C:/Users/user/Downloads/SDL2-devel-2.30.1-mingw/SDL2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -lSDL
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users/user/Downloads/SDL2-devel-2.30.1-mingw/SDL2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
```

I tried including the SDL.dll application file into my debug/build fil of the project but it also didnt work. I'm out of ideas. Maybe its something Im missing.

Comment: `C:/Users/user/Downloads/SDL2-devel-2.30.1-mingw/SDL2/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` that's a long path. Is your user name really user? Or is there a space in it? Are there files with a `.a` extension in this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try using -lSDL2 instead of -lSDL

Comment: This reads like a comment rather than an answer, and it's the fault of "Try". Take some advice from Master Yoda and Do. Or do not. Your call.